# How can I use Ajax to update data in two different input type forms without it clearing information from the other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am creating a webpage which will allow users to upload their own images and create a collage, to which they will be able to add a title and (eventually) save/retrieve by title.

I am currently using Ajax to handle setting the image as background using the JS below:

```
function setUploadedBackground(fileName){
    var ajx;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// If the browser if IE7+[or] Firefox[or] Chrome[or] Opera[or]Safari
        ajx=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {//If browser is IE6, IE5
        ajx=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    ajx.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (ajx.readyState==4 && ajx.status==200)
        {
            //change background
        }
    }
    ajx.open("GET","index.jsp",true);
    ajx.send();
    return false;
}
```

The form "uploadAction" uses the following action jsp to actually upload and save files.

```
<form id= "uploadForm" action="

                    <%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*, javax.servlet.*" %>
                    <%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*" %>
                    <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.*" %>
                    <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*" %>
                    <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*" %>
                    <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.io.output.*" %>

                    <%
                    int uploadFailed = 0;
                    File file ;
                    String fileName = null;
                    int maxFileSize = 500000 * 1024;
                    int maxMemSize = 5000 * 1024;
                    ServletContext context = pageContext.getServletContext();
                    String filePath = context.getInitParameter("file-upload");

                    // Verify the content type
                    String contentType = request.getContentType();
                    //if (contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0) {

                    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
                    // maximum size that will be stored in memory
                    factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
                    // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
                    factory.setRepository(new File("uploads/"));

                    // Create a new file upload handler
                    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
                    upload.setHeaderEncoding("ISO-8858-2");

                    // maximum file size to be uploaded.
                    upload.setSizeMax( maxFileSize );
                    try {
                        // Parse the request to get file items.
                        List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

                        // Process the uploaded file items
                        Iterator iter = fileItems.iterator();

                        while ( iter.hasNext () ) {
                            FileItem fi = (FileItem)iter.next();
                            if ( !fi.isFormField () ) {

                                // Get the uploaded file parameters
                                String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
                                fileName = fi.getName().replaceAll("\\s", "");

                                String mimeType = getServletContext().getMimeType(fi.getName());

                                if(mimeType == null) mimeType = fi.getContentType();
                                if (mimeType.startsWith("image")) {
                                    String command = "update users set mm11='"+fileName+"' where name = 'Gjeta'";
                                    st.executeUpdate(command);

                                    boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
                                    long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();

                                    // Write the file
                                    if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ) {
                                        file = new File( filePath + fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                            file = new File( filePath + fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
                                        }
                                        fi.write( file ) ;
                                    }
                                    else uploadFailed = 2;

                                }
                            }
                        } catch(Exception ex) {
                            System.out.println(ex);
                            if(ex.toString().contains("IOFileUploadException")) uploadFailed = 1;
                        }
                    //}
                    %>"
                        method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input class="uploads" type="file" name="file" size="50"/>
                    <input class="uploadFile" type="submit" value="Upload File"/>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        <% if (uploadFailed == 0) { %>
                        setUploadedBackground('<%=fileName%>');
                        <% } else if (uploadFailed == 1) { %>
                                alert("Maximum file size exceeded");
                                <% } else if (uploadFailed == 2) { %>
                                        alert("Please upload an image");
                                    <% } %>

                    </script>
                </form>
```

My problem is that doing this erases the data in the other form which I use to allow users to input and update the collage title. The code for this is here:

```
<form id = "nameBoardForm" method="post">
    <input type='text' name='collageName' id='collageNameInput' />
    <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submitBtn' value="Save collage" class='enableOnInput' disabled='disabled' />
</form>
```

To update the title using Ajax, I use the JS

```
$( "#nameBoardForm" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
               event.preventDefault();
               console.log( $( this ).serialize().replace(new RegExp("\\+", "g"), ' ') );
               updateTitle($( this ).serialize().replace(new RegExp("\\+", "g"), ' '));

               });
```

I know that the problem is that when uploading a file, the upload form essentially redirects to an action page, and although I use Ajax to set the uploaded image as the background of the container div, the fact that I am not using something like

```
event.preventDefault();
```

means that the form submit causes a redirect, as far as I understand. I have tried using the same kind of logic as my nameBoardForm uses, ie, using jQuery to change what happens on submit but I cannot get the file name parameter I need using serialize() because this just seems to return an empty string for the file input form (even though it works perfectly for the text input form)

Is there any way I can get around this? At the moment if a user uploads an image, it is set as the div background, and then they can also change the collage title from 'Untitled' to their own collage name, using Ajax, without affecting the uploaded image/background of the div. However, if a user sets the name of the collage first, then when an image is uploaded and set to background, the collage title is reset to 'Untitled' thus the user loses the data they have already input...

Eventually the idea is that I will save the filename to a database under the collage title so that users can then search for collages by titles they have used before and have a collage redisplayed based on images they previously uploaded. However, this means that the data input to the collage title is crucial and so cannot be erased by Ajax setting an image as the div background - any advice? I have been googling for a solution for ages but it seems file input forms are weird, and I haven't found anything useful.

EDIT-----------------------

The resulting HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/setUploadedBackground.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/enableButton.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

        <!--script src="params.js" type="text/javascript"></script-->

        <link href="css/newstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>            
        <h3 id="title"><div class="collageTitle">Untitled</div></h3>

        <form id = "nameBoardForm" method="post">
            <input type='text' name='collageName' id='collageNameInput' />
            <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submitBtn' value="Save collage" class='enableOnInput' disabled='disabled' />
        </form>

        <div id="uploadsContainer" class="mm11Container" style="top:100px; left: 300px;">
            <div id="img" class="mm11 card front face">
                <form id= "uploadForm" action=""
                    method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input class="uploads" type="file" name="file" size="50"/>
                    <input class="uploadFile" type="submit" value="Upload File"/>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        <% if (uploadFailed == 0) { %>
                        setUploadedBackground('<%=fileName%>');
                        <% } else if (uploadFailed == 1) { %>
                                alert("Maximum file size exceeded");
                                <% } else if (uploadFailed == 2) { %>
                                        alert("Please upload an image");
                                    <% } %>

                    </script>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="testing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'd better post resulting HTML instead of jsp source.

Comment: I have edited my question to include this